# Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property declared in protocol -- which one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols, synthesize

It's nice that it tells that there is such a property that I have to synthesize, but is there any way I can figure out which one it is w/o going through the documentation? I'm implementing the `UITextInput` `protocol` and can't figure out what's missing.

Comment: You will have to synthesize all properties you inherit through conforming to a protocol. So just synthesize them all.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You will have to explicitly synthesize all properties you inherit through conforming to a protocol. So just synthesize them all.

Comment: is there any way to tell which one I haven't synthesized yet? when there's a missing method it tells you "Method X in protocol is not implemented"

Comment: Check the full build output. You will get an additional message from the compiler after the error identifying which property is missing. Or you can expand the triangle next to the error in the normal error messages window. It should show you "property declared here".